# Master.page doesn't load correctly

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, file-rename

Yesterday I was trying to rename my *.aspx , *.cs, *.designer.cs files and class as well. Now i got issue with properly loading master.page on any page in my website(even that pages which i don't rename). I have no idea what happend I'm sure i doesn't make any mistakes in rename(using refactor). Every page are white but when i push ctrl+F5 combination of buttons the same page are showed correctly. Now i strike my head over the wall;/

Anyone got something like this before?

I hope I describe this problem understandable.

Thanks for advance.

**Edit:** I've made it works just clicked ctrl+shift+del and cleared all from firefox browser and it's started works...

Comment: you must be missing it somewhere, Did you try Ctrl+Shift+F and find the old name in Entire Solution, If that does not found anything, did you try by open Windows Explorer, Go to project directory , press F3 and find the old name in File Contains (for XP)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying adding the master page reference in the config file:

```
<pages masterPageFile="MySite.Master" />
```

Answer (score 0):

That's normal if everything becomes fine, only after ctrl+f5, seems your browser has cached some old named files, and can't apply them to new templates.

But if it isn'tm try to check what could you miss.
1. Check aspx files' code file property on match to new names;
2. Check aspx files' master page file property on match to new master page file.

Open webbrowser's developer tool(e.g. firefox - firebug), and check console for error. That usually helps to determine the error reason.